# realtime count of remote desktop users

Tags: remote-desktop

I'm currently using the following code in a cmd file under task scheduler every 5 mins to grab the total of count of logged on users and write that number to a text file.  My goal in this is to determine the usage the server is getting during the course of a day. I grab the text file and import into Excel and create a grab showing the usage during the given day.  Does anyone have another method for doing this?

```
FOR /F "TOKENS=1* DELIMS= " %%A IN ('DATE/T') DO SET CDATE=%%B
FOR /F "TOKENS=1,2 eol=/ DELIMS=/ " %%A IN ('DATE/T') DO SET mm=%%B
FOR /F "TOKENS=1,2 DELIMS=/ eol=/" %%A IN ('echo %CDATE%') DO SET dd=%%B
FOR /F "TOKENS=2,3 DELIMS=/ " %%A IN ('echo %CDATE%') DO SET yyyy=%%B

SET date=%mm%_%dd%_%yyyy%

for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=:,.: " %%I in ("%TIME%") do set BCKP_TIME=%%I:%%J

::md C:\Stats\%date%

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set EX=0 
set MS=OK 
SET /a COUNT=0
SET USER=
FOR /f "TOKENS=1" %%i IN ('query session ^|find "rdp-tcp#"') DO SET /a COUNT+=1
echo %bckp_time%_%count%>>C:\Stats\%date%.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways but it depends on what you use. If you are running servers, then you probably have a monitoring solution, then that monitoring solution probably has WMI capability or even pluggings to do this which would graph the number of sessions. I use [Zenoss and there is a ZenPack for that](http://wiki.zenoss.org/ZenPack%3aWMI_Terminal_Server). This gives me a graph of number of sessions.

There are also [tons of PowerShell scripts](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/site/search?f%5B0%5D.Type=RootCategory&f%5B0%5D.Value=remotedesktopservices&f%5B0%5D.Text=Remote%20Desktop%20Services) that lists the user sessions - thus you could use this and just get a count - I'm sure there is a PowerShell way to get a count.